# Multi maven project: first and last modules show version when installed

Tags: maven

Just that, when I run the "install" command on any of my maven projects with multiple modules I noticed that the version of the first and the las module are displayed next to the "name" of the module.

This is the output:

```
    Name_Module_1 2.0.0 ....... SUCCESS [  0.484 s]
    Name_Module_2 ............... SUCCESS [  2.312 s]
    Name_Module_3 2.0.0.......... SUCCESS [  0.842 s]
```

As you can see, after the first and the 3rd name there's the "2.0.0" which is the version of the module, but not with the second. The same happened to me with any other projects, always beeing the first and the last modules showing the version.

Why is that? And how can I avoid maven showing any versions?

Comment: You should simply read the release notes of Maven: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.3/release-notes.html and you can't avoid that. Apart from that: What is the problem with that?

Comment: I was just ordered to try to get rid of that just to make the output look "better", not any functional reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output shows the version in the first and the last entry by default which is documented in the [Maven 3.5.3 release notes](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.3/release-notes.html) and can't be turned off.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Maven projects and didn't even knew that was a recent change. Literally 3.5.3 is the first version I touched.